# How to manipulate posted product price data before insert to database in opencart v2?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, opencart2.x

I am a beginner,

I am trying to manipulate posted product price data before saving in opencart v2 but i couldn't do it. I tried that in controller and see my manipulation changes data in View (`product_form.tpl`).

How works recording data on opencart? View (`product_form.tpl`) posts data to Controller (`admin/controller/catalog/product.php`) then Model (`admin/model/catalog/product.php`) takes data from controller, right?

```
if (isset($this->request->post['price'])) {
 $data['price'] = $this->currency->convert($data['currency_price'], $data['product_currency'], $this->config->get('config_currency'));
} elseif (!empty($product_info)) {
 $data['price'] = $product_info['price'];
} else {
 $data['price'] = '';
}
```

Comment: Please post the controller code you tried that isn't working.

Comment: Hi Brain thanks for your comment but i seen your comment today, I will answer my question again to post the controller code

Answer (score 0):

I found that, maybe helps to someone..

If you want to manipulate data when you add product data, you can change variable before query in Model (admin/model/catalog/product.php);

Original Code

```
public function addProduct($data) {
    $this->event->trigger('pre.admin.product.add', $data);

    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product SET model = '" . $this->db->escape($data['model']) . "', sku = '" . $this->db->escape($data['sku']) . "', upc = '" . $this->db->escape($data['upc']) . "', ean = '" . $this->db->escape($data['ean']) . "', jan = '" . $this->db->escape($data['jan']) . "', isbn = '" . $this->db->escape($data['isbn']) . "', mpn = '" . $this->db->escape($data['mpn']) . "', location = '" . $this->db->escape($data['location']) . "', quantity = '" . (int)$data['quantity'] . "', minimum = '" . (int)$data['minimum'] . "', subtract = '" . (int)$data['subtract'] . "', stock_status_id = '" . (int)$data['stock_status_id'] . "', date_available = '" . $this->db->escape($data['date_available']) . "', manufacturer_id = '" . (int)$data['manufacturer_id'] . "', shipping = '" . (int)$data['shipping'] . "', price = '" . (float)$data['price'] . "', points = '" . (int)$data['points'] . "', weight = '" . (float)$data['weight'] . "', weight_class_id = '" . (int)$data['weight_class_id'] . "', length = '" . (float)$data['length'] . "', width = '" . (float)$data['width'] . "', height = '" . (float)$data['height'] . "', length_class_id = '" . (int)$data['length_class_id'] . "', status = '" . (int)$data['status'] . "', tax_class_id = '" . (int)$data['tax_class_id'] . "', sort_order = '" . (int)$data['sort_order'] . "', date_added = NOW()");
```

After Manipulation

```
public function addProduct($data) {
    $this->event->trigger('pre.admin.product.add', $data);
```

$data['price'] = $this->currency->convert($data['currency_price'], $data['currency_product'], $this->config->get('config_currency'));

```
    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product SET model = '" . $this->db->escape($data['model']) . "', sku = '" . $this->db->escape($data['sku']) . "', upc = '" . $this->db->escape($data['upc']) . "', ean = '" . $this->db->escape($data['ean']) . "', jan = '" . $this->db->escape($data['jan']) . "', isbn = '" . $this->db->escape($data['isbn']) . "', mpn = '" . $this->db->escape($data['mpn']) . "', location = '" . $this->db->escape($data['location']) . "', quantity = '" . (int)$data['quantity'] . "', minimum = '" . (int)$data['minimum'] . "', subtract = '" . (int)$data['subtract'] . "', stock_status_id = '" . (int)$data['stock_status_id'] . "', date_available = '" . $this->db->escape($data['date_available']) . "', manufacturer_id = '" . (int)$data['manufacturer_id'] . "', shipping = '" . (int)$data['shipping'] . "', price = '" . (float)$data['price'] . "', points = '" . (int)$data['points'] . "', weight = '" . (float)$data['weight'] . "', weight_class_id = '" . (int)$data['weight_class_id'] . "', length = '" . (float)$data['length'] . "', width = '" . (float)$data['width'] . "', height = '" . (float)$data['height'] . "', length_class_id = '" . (int)$data['length_class_id'] . "', status = '" . (int)$data['status'] . "', tax_class_id = '" . (int)$data['tax_class_id'] . "', sort_order = '" . (int)$data['sort_order'] . "', date_added = NOW()");
```